# Updating all elements in a C++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, lambda

I have a vector of structs - say the struct is something like:

```
struct foo {
  int bar1;
  int bar2;
}
```

Now I want to update each element of my vector and the update is multiplying `bar1` by 2.

The naive way to do this would be to iterate over each element of the vector, but is there a better way of doing this, maybe by using a library function with a c++11 lambda function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) for this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<foo> v;
....
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](foo& f) { f.bar1 *=2; });
```

Whether it is clearer/simpler than a plain loop is another matter. In this simple case, a plain range based loop might be a better option:

```
for (auto& f : v) f.bar1 *= 2;
```

Comment: +1 for signalling that the range-for loop nearly wiped out the uses of `std::for_each`, the only uses I can fathom for the latter would be with `std::bind` when passing it to other functions and that would be quite a mess.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::for_each
#include <vector>

void update_foos(std::vector<foo>& foos)
{
   // Range-based for
   for(auto& foo : foos)
   {
     foo.bar1 *= 2;
   }
   // std::for_each+lambda
   std::for_each(std::begin(foos), std::end(foos), [](foo& f) { f.bar1 *=2; });
}
```